# cannot navigate with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi my code seems fine but I don t know why it s not working

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
         templateUrl: '../pages/index1.html'

    }).when('/profile',{
        templateUrl: '../pages/profile.html',


    }).otherwise('',{templateUrl:'index.html'});
 });
```

index.html

```
<li><a data-ng-href="#/profile.html">Profile</a>
```

Comment: Try without hash and remove .html from href

Comment: Please provide what is and isn't working and what you have tried to get it to work.

Comment: Is there any error you get in console? Why is there a # in ng-href?

Comment: Are you using Angular with any frameworks like nodeJS or Laravel?

Comment: I removed the hash but it takes me to [http://localhost:9000/profile.htm]l  wich is an unavailable resource.but what I need is [http://localhost:9000/pages/profile.htm]l and i dont have any error in console. One more thing I m just using a template bootstrap